# Error when sending message from background.js in Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to send a message from my background.js to my popup, but the background.js gives the following error whenever I try to dispatch a message:

`Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.`.

I have the following code in my background.js, which seems to cause the error.

```
setInterval(()=>{
     chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
         command: "TEST0"
     });
},2000);
```

And my manifest.json is as follows:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "extension-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Chrome extension test.",
  "icons": {

  },
  "chrome_url_overrides": {
  },

  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },

  "permissions": [ "storage", "unlimitedStorage","activeTab","tabs","scripting"],
  "host_permissions": [ "<all_urls>" ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "js/background.js",
    "type": "module"
  },

  "minimum_chrome_version": "88"

}
```

Comment: popup is not a tab.

Comment: i get the error using `chrome.runtime.sendMessage`, which is why i changed i to tabs. so this isnt the issue

Comment: The popup can only receive messages when it's shown.

Comment: is there a way for background to know if the popup is open in mv3? only results i can find are for mv2

Comment: Send a message from the popup to the background and return the information in the response.

Comment: ah i see thank you. use of the response is the piece i was missing.

Comment: Or you can use `chrome.storage`, then it doesn't matter if the popup is open or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question for the sake of others with the same issue. The problem was a conceptual misunderstanding of how communication between different elements in the extension should work.

I had expected that I could just dispatch messages from different parts of my extension (the popup, the background) and set up listeners, and just catch messages if the different parts happened to be available. As it happens chrome extensions don't like this.

So to get data to my popup from my background.js, rather than using `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` in background.js, I dispatched a message from the popup requesting the data, and then used the `sendResponse` function to return the desired data.

Something like this

**background**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {

        if(request === "some data please"){
             sendResponse("here is some data");
        }
    }
);
```

**popup**

```
let response = await chrome.runtime.sendMessage("some data please");

// response === "here is some data"
```